# How do I convert eloquent object to a zero depth array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.8

I have an eloquent object with data from the model which I need to convert to an array and have all indexes from the relations at the same array depth.

I tried `array_flatten(), map(), filter()` and other PHP methods but couldn't get it working correctly.

How I get my relations:

```
    $data = Person::whereIn('id', $this->id[0])->where('school_id', '=', 
    $this->school)->with(['personinfo'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select(
            'person_id',
            'general_info',
        );
    }, 'trades'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select('person_id', 'trade_id')->with('trades');
    }, 'measurements'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select(
            'person_id',
            'measuring_point_1',
            'measuring_point_1_date',
        );
    }])->get();

    return $data->toArray();
```

What results in the array below, this is as close as I could get using different methods.

**This is the outcome of the return function:**

```
array:3 [
  1 => array:17 [
    "school_id" => 6
    "birth_date" => null
    "sex_id" => 1
    "phone_number" => 62452676867897
    "mobile_number" => 62398356786787
    "email" => "example@example.com"
    "personinfo" => array:5 [
      "person_id" => 21
      "general_info" => null
      "health_info" => null
    ]
    "trades" => array:3 [
      "person_id" => 21
      "trade_id" => 2
      "trades" => array:8 [
        "school_id" => 2
        "name" => "blablabla"
      ]
    ]
    "measurements" => array:7 [
      "person_id" => 21
      "measuring_point_1" => null
      "measuring_point_1_date" => null
    ]
  ]
];
```

**I need the array to be like this:**

```
array:3 [
  1 => array:17 [
    "school_id" => 6
    "birth_date" => null
    "sex_id" => 1
    "phone_number" => 624176676867897
    "mobile_number" => 649498356786787
    "email" => "example@example.com"
    "person_id" => 21
    "general_info" => null
    "health_info" => null
    "person_id" => 21
    "trade_id" => 2
    "school_id" => 2
    "name" => "blablabla"
    "person_id" => 21
    "measuring_point_1" => null
    "measuring_point_1_date" => null
    ]
  ]
];
```

Basically, I need to convert the multidimensional array to a zero depth array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i do not understand what you attend and what you get actually. Usually toArray() function works great

Comment: Hi @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro, i want to convert the multidimensional array to a zero depth array.

Comment: the only way you have is looping the array and create your own new array

Comment: Thanks, some kind of refactoring will try that

Comment: Another option is to use QueryBuilder. instead of using eloquent relations, you can join directly. this will achieve the same thing without any post processing.

Comment: I agree with MHewison, you have made a rod for your own back.  Run a more direct query with JOINs so that you don't need to mop up the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom of array flatten with merging the inner with [array-merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as:

```
function arrayFlatten($array) {
   $res = array();
   foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
       if (is_array($v)) $return = array_merge($res, array_flatten($v)); // add recursively
       else $res[$k] = $v; // just add
   }
   return $res;
}
```

Now just return `arrayFlatten($data->toArray());`

Simple [live example](https://3v4l.org/u0Rmv)

Comment: Please help with the housekeeping by closing duplicate questions instead of answering. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972389/2943403

Comment: i don't think this is a duplicate question, since this is a laravel related question and not specifically multidimensional array's. You suggested the use of QueryBuilder right instead of modifying the outcome right? @mickmackusa

Comment: The accepted answer is plucked directly from an answer on the dupe page.  Borderline plagarism.

Answer (score 0):

How i made it work using [dWinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6487675/dwinder)'s answer

```
       $data = Person::whereIn('id', $this->id[0])->where('school_id', '=', $this->school)->with(['personinfo'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select(
            'person_id',
            'general_info',
        );
    }, 'trades'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select('person_id', 'trade_id')->with('trades');
    }, 'measurements'=>function ($query) {
        $query->select(
            'person_id',
            'measuring_point_1',
            'measuring_point_1_date',
        );
    }])->get();


function array_flatten($array)
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));
            } else {
                $return[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $result[] = array_flatten($value->toArray());
    }


    return $result;
```